# What morphisms induce injective/surjective maps on (Weil) cohomology?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, cohomology

Let $k$ be a field, let $f \colon X \to Y$ be a morphism of $k$-varieties, and assume $X$ and $Y$ are smooth and projective. Let $H(\_)$ be a classical Weil cohomology theory (i.e. one of $\ell$-adic étale, Betti, algebraic de Rham, crystalline). *Of course it depends on $k$ which of the theories are applicable, but I do not want to spell all the cases out here.*

> What conditions can one impose on $f$ to assert that $f^{*} \colon H^{i}(Y) \to H^{i}(X)$ is injective/surjective?

Currently I can only think of the rather trivial: if $f$ admits a section (resp. retraction), then $f^{*}$ is injective (resp. surjective).

**[Edit]** For example, is it true that $f^{*}$ is injective if $f$ is dominant? **[/Edit]**

Comment: Someone may hit this with the CW-hammer if you think a “one property/condition” per answer style would be best.

Comment: Do dominant non-surjective morphisms of smooth projective varieties really exist?  I would have thought some valuative criterion would get violated.

Comment: Well, over $\mathbb{C}$ I would say that they do not exist. Using the analytic topology, the image of the morphism must be compact (since $X$ is compact and $f \colon X \to Y$ is continuous), hence closed (since $Y$ is Hausdorff). On the other hand, the image contains a dense open set (since the map is dominant), so the image is actually the whole of $Y$ (by a dimension argument).

Comment: @S.Carnahan — Good point. (Thanks Francesco for the argument—at least over $\mathbb{C}$.)

Comment: @FrancescoPolizzi: over any field, the image of a projective variety is closed, and that's all you use, right? (Or did I misunderstand something?)

Comment: true, projective schemes are proper :-) I'm used to think in the complex category and I wrote the first proof on the top of my head, but it seems to me that you are completely right.

Comment: @ArtiePrendergast-Smith – Thanks for your comment. In the end I should have realised this myself. Anyway, I didn't know Kleiman's result, so Timo's answer + your comment really answers my question!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Kleiman, Algebraic Cycles and the Weil Conjectures, Proposition 1.2.4: Let $f: X \to Y$ be surjective. Then $f^*: H^*(Y) \to H^*(X)$ is injective.

Let me recall the proof.

Let $x$ be a closed point of the generic fibre of $f$ and set $Z := \overline{\{z\}} \subseteq X$ and let $z = cl(Z)$ be the cycle class of $Z$. Since the cycle class map commutes with $f_*$, one has $f_*(z) \neq 0$.

Now assume $a \in H^*(Y)$ is in the kernel of $f^*$. Then one has $f^*(ab)z = f^*(a)f^*(b)z = 0$ for every $b \in H^*(Y)$, so by the projection formula $0 = f_*(f^*(ab)z) = abf_*(z)$, so by Poincaré duality $a = 0$.

Comment: Ok, cool. Do you know if dominant is enough?

Comment: If $X$ and $Y$ are projective, then dominant implies surjective.

Comment: @DanPetersen – Of course, I should have realised this myself. Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

For posterity, and as it was a bit tricky to find a reference, note also that the statement holds for possibly non-projective, quasi-projective smooth varieties, or, more generally for non-compact smooth Kähler manifolds:

**Theorem (Wells):** Let $f:X\to Y$ be a proper surjective morphism of smooth complex manifolds and assume that $X$ is Kähler. Then the following induced homomorphisms are injective

1. $f^*:H^q(Y,\Omega^p_Y)\to H^q(X,\Omega^p_X)$
2. $f^*:H^k(Y,\mathbb{C})\to H^k(X,\mathbb{C})$
3. $f^*:H^k(Y,\Omega^p_Y(E))\to H^k(X,\Omega^p_X(f^*E))$ for a holomorphic vector bundle $E$.

The reference is Wells [Comparison of de Rham and Dolbeault cohomology for proper surjective mappings](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.pjm/1102911803).

Answer (score 5):

I do not know any effective, general criterion. But the Lefschetz hyperplane theorem for complex algebraic varieties tells you that if you have a hyperplane section $X\subset Y$ where $Y$ is a complex projective algebraic smooth variety of dimension $n$ such that $Y-X$ is smooth then the induced map 
$$H^*(Y,\mathbb{Z})\rightarrow H^*(X,\mathbb{Z})$$
is an isomorphism for $*<n-1$ and an injection for $*=n-1$.

...................

Edit: Let $Y$ be a smooth complex projective variety and let 
$D$ be a normal crossing divisor ($dim_{\mathbb{C}}(Y)=n$). If the contraction $Y/D$ is algebraic projective and if the map $Y\rightarrow Y/D$ is also algebraic then 
$$H^i(Y,\mathbb{C})\rightarrow H^i(D,\mathbb{C})$$
is surjective for $i\geq n$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! This is indeed a criterion, but not exactly the flavour that I was looking for (no offense!).

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand the last paragraph. Are there some missing hypotheses?

Comment: OK, I see. I misunderstood your notation. In algeometer-speak, you're saying: suppose $D$ can be contracted to a point, then... And you're getting this from the decomposition theorem.