# Surjectivity of Étale cohomology

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, etale-cohomology

I've come across https://mathoverflow.net/q/172523, which says that if $D\subset Y$ is a contractible divisor, then we have a surjection
$$H^n(Y,\mathbb{C})\rightarrow H^n(D,\mathbb{C})$$
for $n\geq \text{dim }Y$. I don't quite know the proof to this statement and would like to know. In a remark to this post, it is mentioned that the decomposition theorem is used in the proof, and I don't know how.

Furthermore, I'm curious if this is true for higher codimensions, i.e. if $C$ is an algebraic cylce of arbitrary codimension, do we have a similar statement? One way one could get such a statement is if we have a sequence
$$(*)\quad C\subset D_1\subset \ldots \subset D_c\subset Y$$
of subspaces of $Y$ such that $D_{i-1}$ is a contractible divisor of $D_i$, which would give us a surjection
$$H^n(Y,\mathbb{C})\rightarrow H^n(C,\mathbb{C})$$
even though I have no idea how to get such a chain $(*)$ or how to describe those cycles for which such a chain exists.

Comment: The proof applies to a closed subscheme $Z$ such that there is a map out of $Y$ that is an isomorphism away from $Y$ and contracts $Z$ to a point.