Is pullback map on sheaf cohomology injective for surjective morphisms?
Consider a surjective map $f\colon X\to Y$ of smooth projective varieties. It is well known (see e.g. Voisin's Hodge theory I, Lemma 7.28) that the map $H^i(Y,\mathbb Q)\to H^i(X,\mathbb Q)$ is injective.
Question: Can we replace $\mathbb Q_Y$ with some other sheaf $L$ in this statement? Namely, is it true that the map
$$
H^i(Y,L)\to H^i(X,f^*L)
$$
is injective for, say, $L$ local system or of geometric origin, or constructible?
Remark: $X$ and $Y$ are over $\mathbb C$ and cohomology is Betti cohomology.

Say $i=1$. What if $H^1$ vanishes for $X$? But I'm not an algebraic geometer, so I don't have good intuition

Although the question itself is not a clear duplicate, there is an answer which applies to this question as well: https://mathoverflow.net/a/317691/15782 The answer is yes, by a theorem due to Wells.

@Ben: the theorem of Wells in the linked answer applies to the case where $L$ is a vector bundle. But the OP is asking about other kinds of sheaves.

You're right, @LazzaroCampeotti, thank you. Then let's just say that the answer is yes for vector bundles.

By the projection formula, it is enough to show that $\mathbf{Q}Y \to Rf* \mathbf{Q}_X$ is split (i.e., has a left inverse). This follows, e.g., by the decomposition theorem (or by slicing to the case of generically finite $f$ and using Poincare duality as well as the fact that multiplication by the generic degree $f$ is an isomorphism on $\mathbf{Q}_Y$).

sounds right @Anonymous, thank you!
